# get the value of a newly created html attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hey there i am trying to create a new html attribute for which i am following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644358/html-javascript-add-attribute-to-an-html-control), in which i have succeeded. i am also trying to echo the value of the attribute in a number of the same html tags, which in this case is an `<a>` tag, which is inside a div tag and am using the `jquery` `.find()` to get the value of those attributes in those `<a>` tags. but i only get one attribute value, which is the first one, but not the rest, basically i want to echo the value of the attribute in all the `<a>` tags. how can i do this, oh and a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Roy_S/Y57G2/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe `.each()` to loop through each node

```
$("#gh").click(function() {
    $("#new_attr").find('.showItLink').each(function(){
      alert($(this).attr("textToShow"));
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y57G2/3/)

If you want to get the exact node which contains a specific attribute value, use like this

```
 $('.showItLink[textToShow="This is the text to show0"]')
```

[**Fiddle 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y57G2/5/)

Answer (score 0):

you acheive the scenario through `.each()` in jquery

```
$("#gh").click(function() {


   $("#new_attr").find('.showItLink').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr("textToShow") == "This is the text to show5") {
        alert ('found');
    }else{
        alert ('not found');
    }


    });

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y57G2/4/)